# Pip is correctly installing libraries to the proper directory, but I cannot import those packages properly in program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-import

I installed (with pip) MatPlotLib and Pandas, and they are both not working properly in programs. Here is the strange thing... 
When I type the following into the interactive environment of IDLE
import pandas as pd

pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

I get this as output: (indicating that it works properly)

0    1

1    2

2    3

3    4

4    5

dtype: int64

But when I use that very same code in a python program, it crashes and says "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Series'"

Can anyone tell me what's going on?
I can also successfully import matplotlib in the interactive environment but get errors when I do it in a program and run it.

EDIT: There is no shebang because I am running the program through IDLE. I am using python 3.6, the only python I have on my computer. I am executing this file by clicking run in IDLE.

Currently In my command prompt paths I have 
C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\

EDIT 2: I think we are closer to finding out the problem. If I run a python program with the code above in the command line (this time with the proper shebang(I forgot one before)), it works! So this must be an idle issue. 
Currently, one of IDLE's paths is to 
C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages
which contains all of the libraries for python.

EDIT FINAL: SOLVED. So when I did:

import sys

sys.path.append(path to pandas library) it worked! so now I can fully use pandas. I guess I will just have to do this anytime I download a new library and it doesn't work. Thank you for all the help

Comment: show us your program

Comment: the program is identical to the code typed into the interactive environment. In fact I just ran it again in i.e. and it worked, then copied and pasted it into the program and it failed.

Comment: Show us how the program is being invoked, which Python installation is run, the shebang in the script, and so on.

Comment: how exactly and from what shell do you invoke the program?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "How the program is being invoked" please?

Comment: How you start the execution. From IDLE with "Run Module" or from your OS shell with `python mymodule.py` for example.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you update the question and add the values of `PYTHONPATH`, the path to `python` in both `path` and `IDE settings`?

Comment: Strange, it works for me. You won't see output unless you print the Series with `print(pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))` but that's not causing the problem.

Comment: @alvits sorry for noob question but how should I go about finding all of that. Are there commands I could enter in the command line to get that info?

Comment: It depends on your OS. In Linux you can use `which python` and `which pip` to see the paths of `python` and `pip`. You can also `echo $PYTHONPATH` to see if it is set. In IDE, it depends on the IDE how to find the `python path`. The IDE may have a different `PYTHONPATH` where it installs and fetches all modules such as `panda`.

Comment: I'm running windows 10 so i'll look it up right now. Also, when I type python in my search bar I see that it is 3.63, but on python.org the newest version (from 10/12/20170 is 3.64. Could that be causing these issues?

Comment: No. But you may have multiple instance of `python` or `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: But how does it make sense he can import pandas but pandas has no Series? If pandas wouldn't be reachable you would expect an `ImportError`

Comment: I have added an edit with some relevant information.

Comment: If modifying the path solved the problem, then I question whether Pip installed into the proper directory.

Comment: Ok so, it didn't. This incredible weird thing is now happening with matplotlib. I had to manually install matplotlib and put it into the site-packages folder. After doing so I was finally able to import matplotlib. But guess what, I cannot get pyplot from matplot lab. So the code "from matplotlib import pyplot" doesn't work... So confusing..

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. So when I did:

import sys

sys.path.append(path to pandas library)

it worked! so now I can fully use pandas. I guess I will just have to do this anytime I download a new library and it doesn't work. Thank you for all the help

Comment: This is not the correct way to do this. There is another issue that you have not solved which is preventing you from importing. You should not need to append the path. Are you trying to import `pandas` from the `pandas` directory?